# Update iOS Phonegap App from AppleStore and keep previous user persistent data

Tags: cordova, updates

Hello i'm new to iOS and Phonegap developpement.
I have tried PhoneGap with Xcode for testing and I'm about to build my first app that will go to the app store.

My question is that in my app users will do stuff and have their own data (file and or database localstorage). I want to be sure to create the correct architecture to be able to update my app in case off evolutions but keep users data. It would be a big drama if after my update users looses their data.

by reading this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW10
and this http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter
, I guess that i can make things works for files but how ...

then what about localstorage and database ?

If you have code samples it would be wonderfull.
regards,